# How to prevent duplicate entries in Jquery Sortable connection list?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

i have two asp dropdown list.. based on the values selected in two dropdown list it will generate two unordered list dynamically in which i have implemented Jquery Sortable connection list.. The first list contains some default values.. I need to drag and drop the required values to the second list... It should prevent adding duplicate entries..

I am pasting my code below... Kindly check that and provide me a solution:

This is the aspx code for two dropdownlist:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

       Application <asp:DropDownList ID="ApplicationList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="FetchRoleFromApplication" >
          </asp:DropDownList>

      Role <asp:DropDownList ID="RoleName" runat="server" onchange="javascript:ShowSortable();"  >
       </asp:DropDownList>

    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" runat="server" style="display:none">

   </ul>


   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" style="display:none" runat="server" >

    </ul>
    </form>
```

The first ul list is independent so its values is loaded in the codebehind(pageload)  like this:

```
 HtmlGenericControl li;
        JavaScriptSerializer objJSSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        foreach (FetchUserGroup_Result objectItem in Allusergroup)
        {
            li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            li.ID = objectItem.group_id.ToString();
            li.Attributes.Add("class", "ui-state-default");
            li.InnerText = objectItem.group_name;

            sortable1.Controls.Add(li);
        }
```

The second ul list values are loaded by an ajax call like this...

```
function ShowSortable() {

    $('#sortable1').show();


    var postJSONData = JSON.stringify({ ApplicationId: $('#applnhdnname').val(), RoleName: $('#RoleName').val() });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postJSONData,
        url: 'UserManagementService.svc/GetUserGroupsForApplicationRole',

        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function success(response) {

            $("#sortable2").append(response.d);
            $('#sortable2').show();

        },
        error: SessionExpiryHandler
    });
}
```

The corresponding wcf service is this:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string GetUserGroupsForApplicationRole(string ApplicationId, string RoleName)
        {

            User user = new User();
            JavaScriptSerializer objJSSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<GetUserGroupForApplicationRole_Result> usergroup;
            usergroup = user.GetUserGroupForApplicationRole(ApplicationId, RoleName);
            string sample = string.Empty;

            foreach (GetUserGroupForApplicationRole_Result objectItem in usergroup)
            {

                sample += "<li id= "+objectItem.group_id+ " class='ui-state-highlight'>";
                sample += objectItem.group_name;
                sample+="</li>";

            }


            return sample;
        }
```

How to avoid duplicate value in this... Please help me out..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your javascript as follows:

```
 <script>
    function ShowSortable() {

        $('#sortable1').show();


        var postJSONData = JSON.stringify({ ApplicationId: $('#applnhdnname').val(), RoleName: $('#RoleName').val() });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: postJSONData,
            url: 'UserManagementService.svc/GetUserGroupsForApplicationRole',

            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            success: function success(response) {
                for(var i=0; i<response.d.length;i++)
                {

                    var myOption = $("<option value= " + response.d[i] + "> " + response.d[i] + " </option>");
                    if ($("#sortable2").length == 0) {
                        $("#sortable2").append(myOption);

                    }
                    $("#sortable2> option").each(function() {

                        if (response.d[i] != this.value) {
                            $("#sortable2").append(myOption);

                        }


                    });
                }

                $('#sortable2').show();
            },
            error: SessionExpiryHandler
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: in this code  $("#sortable2> option").each(function() {

    if(response.d[i] != this.value)      It check for the duplicate value in the second list

Comment: Is ther a chance to be duplicate values from first dropdown?

Comment: No... I have two list..1st list is independent  For instance it just contains some 5 values.. 2nd list loads its value from ajax which will contain some values among the 5 values in 1st list.. I will add additional values from 1st list to 2nd list.. If i try to add the same value which is already ben loaded by ajax it should prevent me

Comment: your solution gives my 2nd list as empty list... I already have some values in that.. I am just adding something as explained in my previous comment

Comment: how u are dragging the values from first list to second?

Comment: That's what the work of the plugin.. It does that job.. I will just included that plugin in my aspx...

Comment: its only done on the function call of ShowSortable. How the drag process done here?

Comment: if(response.d[i] != this.value) is it you need or $("#applnhdnname >option") .each(function(){ ......... is it needed/

Comment: Dropdown values does not appear in the list...Based on Dropdown values list values are generated For example.. 1st list contains value like a,b,c,d,e.. 2nd list will have b,c.. now if i drag b or c and drop in 2nd list it should prevent me.. i should be able to add oly a,d,e

Comment: Actually you are not understanding... I have some values in 2nd list.. Once i try your code i am getting an empty 2nd list..

Comment: Do u know debugging in javascript? pls debug and find where the data miss in the second list.